# Como desactivar el salto de fila al presionar Enter en un DataGridView en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen día, tengo un programa en el que quiero obtener el valor de la primera celda en una fila seleccionada del `DataGridView` , ya lo tengo hecho al hacer doble click sobre la fila con el evento `CellDoubleClick` de esta forma

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string valorPrimerCelda = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Ahora estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo con el evento `KeyPress` para que al estar seleccionada una celda de la fila al presionar la tecla <kbd>enter</kbd> me regrese el valor de la primera celda y lo estoy haciendo de esta forma:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
            string valorPrimerCelda = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
        }
    }
```

funciona relativamente bien, el problema es que la acción predeterminada al presionar <kbd>enter</kbd> en un `DataGridView` es hacer un salto a la fila de abajo, y parece que hace esto antes de ejecutar mi código por lo que el valor que me recupera es el de la celda que esta justo debajo de la que necesito.

Hay alguna forma de desactivar este comportamiento? , solo el del <kbd>enter</kbd> por que quiero seguir ocupando las flechas para navegar dentro del `DataGridView` , o hay alguna forma de restarle una fila a mi variable `row`?

muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para solucionar tu problema tenes que usar el evento [`KeyDown`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=netframework-4.7.2) en lugar de [`KeyPress`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netframework-4.7.2), ya que este se ejecuta antes y te permitirá prevenir que se cambie a la siguiente fila.

Sabiendo esto, para prevenirlo, tendremos que usar la propiedad [`Handled`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled?view=netframework-4.7.2) de la clase [`KeyEventArgs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Si [`Handled`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled?view=netframework-4.7.2) es `true` implica que nosotros manejamos el evento por nosotros mismos, así que no producirá ninguna acción por defecto, por lo cual, allí esta tu solución.

```
private void DataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{            

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow;
        string valorPrimerCelda = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo esto funciono

Answer (score 1):

Cuando necesitas controlar el evento del teclado en el grid necesitas hacerlo a nivel de la celda, no del Datagridview.

Por eso que deberias adjuntarte al evento `KeyUp` o `KeyDown` de la celda en concreto.

Algo como esto

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
}

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
    dText.KeyUp -= new KeyEventHandler(text_KeyUp);
    dText.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(text_KeyUp);
}

void text_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = ((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)(sender)).EditingControlRowIndex;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        string valorPrimerCelda = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

[SuppressKeyPress](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

**Respuesta**
Yo utilice este código para solucionar ese detalle en el datagrid, utilice el try y catch porque en campos texbox marca unos detalles. por si te sirve.

```
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {

        try
        {
            int icolumn = DataGridViewBUNI.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int irow = DataGridViewBUNI.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (icolumn == DataGridViewBUNI.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    DataGridViewBUNI.Rows.Add();
                    DataGridViewBUNI.CurrentCell = DataGridViewBUNI[0, irow + 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGridViewBUNI.CurrentCell = DataGridViewBUNI[icolumn + 1, irow];
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);


    }
```

> DataGridViewBUNI // Aquí cambias el nombre de tu dgv